# How to use the output of one method as the input on another?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, methods

I'm trying to figure out how to use the output of algorithm as the input of findLarge.
algorithm produces an array that I would like to work on in findLarge

```
class CSVParser
{

    public $output = NULL;
    public $digits = NULL;
    public $largest = NULL;

    public function __construct($file)
    {


        if (!file_exists($file)) {
            throw new Exception("$file does not exist");
        }

        $this->contents = file_get_contents($file);
        $this->output = array();
        $this->digits = array();
        $this->largest = array();
    }

    public function algorithm() {....}

    public function findLarge($a)
    {
        // just push it back so I know it's working
        var_export($a); // is NULL
        $this->largest = $a; // return NULL
    }

}

$parser->algorithm();
$parser->findlarge($input); print_r($parser->largest);
```

Comment: Why not `$parser->findlarge($parser->algorithm());`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're just looking for:

```
$parser->findlarge($parser->algorithm());
```

You might want to consider, however, a couple of things.

1. PHP already has [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)
2. Whether it might be a better idea for `algorithm` to call `findLarge` on its own. It looks like this class has two conflicting purposes. One is storing the data, the other is processing it. You might want to think about either having `algorithm` stateless and having a separate DO, or having algorithm modify the instance's state.